# Relaunch PS script as admin with all parameters

Tags: powershell

I have made a PowerShell script that takes a few parameters and this script needs be launched as admin.
I only have 2 types of parameters in my script: switch and string:

```
Param (
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $false,
    )][switch]$SkipUpdate = $true,
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $false,
    )][switch]$UserReport = $true,
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $false,
    )][switch]$ComputerReport = $true,
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $false,
    )][string]$SearchScope = ""
)
```

The script is launched like this:

```
.\MyScript.ps1 -Param1:$false -Param2 "Some text"
```

Using Google, I quickly found this code:

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]"Administrator")) {
    Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`" $PSCommandArgs" -Verb RunAs
    exit
}
```

It's asking for admin rights but it forgets all parameters once relaunched as admin

I've also found another script on [this website](https://powershell.org/2013/04/powershell-script-that-relaunches-as-admin/)
It looked very interesting but it's not working (code is maybe outdated)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, a robust self-elevation implementation with parameter passthrough and working-directory preservation is quite complex and has inherent limitations. The linked duplicate is a reusable best-effort approach.
Situationally you may get away with simpler implementations.

Comment: As an aside: There is no automatic `$PSCommandArgs` variable, but there is an [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters),  which is a dictionary containing the bound parameters and their values, but the challenge lies in encoding them for use via `Start-Process`.